# GetJdbcTemplate() как проверить, что таблица пустая?

Tags: mysql, java, sql

Пытаюсь выгрузить данные из некоторой таблицы с помощью `getJdbcTemplate()`.    
Проблема в том, что иногда таблица, к которой идет запрос, пустая. Как можно это отлавливать?

Запрос крайне прост:

```
SELECT * FROM wa_source_correction
```

Answer (score 1):

Select * from table вернет пустой результат.

Но я бы ориентировался не на количество записей в таблице, а количество записей, вытянутых твоим запросом.

Comment: запрос как раз так все и вытягивает (добавил в описание). Так то прокатывает, когда считаю число строк в таблице... но думал, что есть более красивое решение

Comment: А зачем это знать вообще надо? При выгрузке получай данные и если данных, удовлетворяющих запосу, нет - выводи ошибку. А лишними запросами проверять пуста ли таблица в данный момент - это, как минимум, лишняя нагрузка на БД, хоть и мизерная.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на иерархию [DataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html). Конкретно на [EmptyResultDataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html).